# How to parse XML using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-grouping

I have an XML with data as follows

```
<Item1>
  <item2>
    <Item3>111</Item3>
  <Item2>
</Item11>
```

To get the value 111 in **Item3**

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:value-of select="Item1/Item2/Item3"/>
</xsl:choose>
```

In XSLT . Now I need to get the following:

```
<Product1>
  <Product2>
    <Product3 ValidYN="Y" ProducType="ABC">333</Product3>
    <Product3 ValidYN="Y" ProducType="DEF">444</Product3>
    <Product3 ValidYN="Y" ProducType="GHI">555</Product3>
  <Product12>
</Product1>
```

I need to take values **333** , **444** , **555** based on **ProducType**.How to do the same using XSLT

Comment: What do you mean when you say "take" those values based on ProducType? What should the result of the XSLT look like?

Comment: Using first sample I was able to reach to value  **111** .Now I need to get values 333,444,555 but the xml tags are similar for those except ** ProducType="ABC" ,ProducType="DEF" ,ProducType="GHI"** .What will be the code for reach these values ,similar to `<xsl:value-of select="Item1/Item2/Item3"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select a node based on values in relation to it, you can use XPaths like this:

```
/Product1/Product2/Product3[@ValidYN = 'Y' and @ProductType = 'ABC']
/Product1/Product2/Product3[@ValidYN = 'Y' and @ProductType = 'DEF']
/Product1/Product2/Product3[@ValidYN = 'Y' and @ProductType = 'GHI']
```

the parts in [square brackets] are called "predicates."

Comment: If need to check this `ValidYN="Y"' also along with `ProducType="ABC"` then??

Comment: Please see my modified answer.